# Find all Data within Geometric view port in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query, geospatial

I am trying to get all data within viewport

```
"viewport": {
            "northeast": {
                "lat": -33.8652709197085,
                "lng": 151.1972016802915
            },
            "southwest": {
                "lat": -33.8679688802915,
                "lng": 151.1945037197085
            }
        }
```

i have data in collection with data like

```
{data:"Block 1", location: { "coordinates" : [ 77.58556519999999, 12.943470099999999 ], "type" : "Point" }}
```

i tried it query on mongodb as

`location: {
                    $near: {
                        $geometry: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [27, 83.22].55
                        },
                        $maxDistance: 3000
                    }
                }`

but i want data within rectange frame how can i acgheve that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "viewport"? All you have are two points. Do you mean the northeast and southwest corners of a square? Or something else? `$nearSphere` will return "nearest" and optionally within a max distance as a "circular" radius. Could do with some clarification.

Comment: I get data like viewport that is left-top and button-right from client side and I have to find all data within that area

Comment: I think you mean "square" yet despite me actually saying that before you're still using this term where we have no idea what you mean. So you probably mean `$geoWithin`, but it's up to you to define the other two points in the "square". `$geoWithin` can take any shape really, but not a "diagonal line" which is all you've given us in the question.

Comment: ya I find the answer in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#op._S_box thanks for your support